# Erro na hora de procurar uma string

Tags: string, python-3.x, debug

> Olá, tudo bem?
>   Estou tendo uma problema na execução deste código.
>   A partir do segundo "While True" o programa não consegue encontrar o produto escrito. Sendo que o mesmo foi cadastrado logo acima. Verifiquei este código de cabo a rabo e não encontrei nada que possa ser considerado erro. 
>   Se alguem conseguir me ajudar a solucionar este empasse, fico agradecido. 
>   Vou deixar disponivel o link do repl.it para que você verifique o erro que está acontecendo.
>   https://repl.it/repls/GoldFrivolousDragonfly

```
print('='*20, 'Cadastrador de produtos', '='*20)
def cadastros():
  cod = int(input('Digite o CÓDIGO do produto: '))
  item = input('Informe o produto que deseja cadastro: ')
  valor = input('Valor do produto: R$').replace(',',',')
  itens.append([cod,item, valor])
itens = []
while True:
  print('-='*20)
  deseja = str(input('Deseja cadastrar um item? S/N ')).upper().strip()
  if deseja == 'S':
    cadastros()
    print('Produto cadastrado com SUCESSO')
  elif deseja == 'N':
    break
  else:
    print('Entrada inválida')
    continue
print('Produtos cadastrados: {}'.format(itens))
print('='*70)
while True:
  x = 0
  op = input('Deseja procurar algum produto? [S/N]: ').upper().strip()
  if op == 'S':
    codPro = str(input('NOME DO PRODUTO: ')).upper().strip()
    for x in range(len(itens)):
      if codPro == itens[x][1]: # <--- Programa com erro na hora de procurar por nome do produto.## Cabeçalhos ##
        print('')
        print('Código: {}\nProduto: {}\nValor: R${}'.format(itens[x][0], codPro, itens[x][2]))
        print('')
      else: 
        print('Nome Invalido, tente novamente')
        continue
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está na seguinte linha:

```
         codPro = str(input('NOME DO PRODUTO: ')).upper().strip()
```

Com o `upper`, você torna todas as letras do input dado em maiúsculas. Assim, se o seu produto tiver letras minúsculas no nome, a comparação não resultará em True. Tente cadastrar um produto com o nome com letras maiúsculas e verá que funciona.

Solução: Tire o `.upper()`.

Note que também não é necessário usar o `str` em `input`; a saída já é uma string.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tudo certo!